# SQL: Select all rows that meet a condition if that condition is met, but only a certain nuber rows if it isn't

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a requirement for an SQL Server 2005 query I need to write and it's stumping me how to accomplish it.
I'll simplifiy it quite a bit, but the essence is that, if a client has no billings more recent than a certain date, I need to select up to 3 of that client's most recent billings. But if they have billings after that cutoff date, just display any of those billings.

So, if my cutoff date is Jan 1, 2010 and the data I have is as follows:

```
ClaimID ClientID    BillingDate
1           1          March 12, 2010
2           1          June 3, 2010
3           1          January 5, 2008
4           1          February 9, 2011
5           1          May 19, 2005
6           2          November 20, 2005
7           2          October 5, 2009
8           3          January 4, 1999
9           3          July 8, 1997
10         3          May 7, 2010
11         3          August 6, 1999
12         4          May 25, 2000
13         4          April 1, 2005
14         4          March 9, 2009
15         4          December 5, 2007
16         4          December 19, 1998
17         4          June 3, 2006
```

Then I want to select:

```
ClaimID ClientID    BillingDate
1           1          March 12, 2010
2           1          June 3, 2010
4           1          February 9, 2011
6           2          November 20, 2005
7           2          October 5, 2009
10         3          May 7, 2010
14         4          March 9, 2009
15         4          December 5, 2007
17         4          June 3, 2006
```

Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: How many of "any"  do you need to display?

Comment: All of them. If the billing occurs after the cutoff date, display it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Rank the rows for every Client by descending `BillingDate`.
2. For every client, output the dates that either:

   - are more recent than the cut-off date, or
   - belong to the 3 highest-ranked ones.

The query:

```
;WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY BillingDate DESC)
  FROM Billings
)
SELECT ClaimID, ClientID, BillingDate
FROM ranked
WHERE BillingDate > @CutOffDate OR rownum BETWEEN 1 AND 3
```

Comment: I think from what the OP has said, the "display all of them" is meant to apply to all billings that occur after the cutoff date - so I think you can simplify your query - remove the inner join to the second reference to ranked, and just apply `BillingDate > @CutOffDate OR rownum BETWEEN 1 AND 3` to the ranked rows.

Comment: @Damien: Why, indeed! It says: 'any of *those* billings.' *Much* simpler now. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: I think that should say `ORDER BY BillingDate DESC`. Your query gets the 3 oldest bills.

Comment: Even though I explicitly stated in my description, that it should get the 3 newest ones... Isn't there the answer consistency parser on SO yet? Oh well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `UNION ALL` to combine the results of two queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE BillingDate > '1-Jan-2010'

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM MyTable T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM MyTable T2
                  WHERE T1.ClientID = T2.ClientID AND T2.BillingDate > '1-Jan-2010')
AND ClaimID IN (SELECT TOP 3 T3.ClaimID
                FROM MyTable T3
                WHERE T1.ClientID = T3.ClientID
                ORDER BY T3.BillingDate DESC)
```

Comment: The `NOT EXISTS` clause in the second query eliminates rows which match the first query. So the query does do "either or" and does *not* do "both".

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should solve your problem? You can even make this a subselect if u want to

```
select ClaimID, ClientID, BillingDate
from bills
where BillingDate > @cutoffDate
UNION ALL
select ClaimID, ClientID, BillingDate
from bills a
where not exists (select 1 from bills b
         where b.ClientId = a.ClientId
           and b.BillingDate > @cutoffDate)
  and 3 >       (select count(1) from bills b
                 where b.ClientId = a.ClientId
                   and b.BillingDate>a.BillingDate)
```